# How to join two tables with special conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two DataFrames with the same features:

```
 customer_id    Class    value  
 1              A        13  
 2              A        14   
 3              B        15

 customer id    Class    value
 1              A        16
 2              B        17
 3              B        18
 4              A        20
```

Now I want 1 DataFrame, one including customers with changing their class from A to B

```
 customer_id    Class    value
 2              B        17
```

How can I do that?

Comment: How did you derive value = 16 for customer_id = 2 & Class = B ?

Comment: I just want how I know  which customers changes from Class A to B. Sr I should give value 17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your DataFrames are `df1` and `df2`, you can merge them on the customers:

```
before_after = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='customer', how='left', suffixes=('_before', '_after'))
```

Then check which changed from `'A'` to `'B'`:

```
before_after[(before_after.id_before == 'A') & (before_after.id_after == 'B')]
```

Comment: I think when I merged I will lose the value of customer_id 4:-?

Comment: @Homesand why is it losing, though? If it is only in that table, it can’t be part of a relevant transition, no?

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a mapping before filtering your second dataframe:

```
df2['Class_original'] = df2['customer_id'].map(df1.set_index('customer_id')['Class'])

res = df2[(df2['Class_original'] == 'A') & (df2['Class'] == 'B')]

print(res)

   customer_id Class  value Class_original
1            2     B     17              A
```